# Can multiple Android Wears can be paired to a single Android Device

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, pairing

Is it possible to pair multiple Android wears pointing or paring to a single Android device?

Running Android 4.3 and above. 
I know that an Android wear cannot be paired with two or more Android devices and I experimented that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pair **multiple android wear** devices (watches) with a **single** phone.

✅ `w* <-> p`

But you can't do the other way (pairing one android wear device (watch) to multiple phones is **not** supported [*officially*](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/08/26/android-wear-beelink-finally-lets-you-pair-your-watch-with-a-new-device-relatively-painlessly/)).

❌ `w <-> p*`

For details have a look at Google's [support page](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6058799).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they can be connected at the same time, but I have two Android Wear devices associated with my phone.

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment (5.0.1W) only one phone per wear device.